# Relationship between ScalaMeta, ScalaFix, and SemanticDB

Tags: scala, scalameta, scalafix, semanticdb

I have the following information:

- Scalameta: has the ability to produce ASTs from a source file
- SemanticDB: Contains information about symbols from a parsed source
  file
- ScalaFix: is based on ScalaMeta and SemanticDB so it has the ability to access symbol information and traverse ASTs.

Loading a source file using
 ScalaMeta is as easy as the following:

```
val path = java.nio.file.Paths.get("path to source file")
val bytes = java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(path)
val text = new String(bytes, "UTF-8")
val input = Input.VirtualFile(path.toString, text)
val tree = input.parse[Source].get
```

As you can observe from the above code snippet, ScalaMeta parses the source file as type `Source`.

Now consider the below code snippet where ScalaFix uses a tree of type `SemanticDocument`:

```
class NamedLiteralArguments extends SemanticRule("NamedLiteralArguments") {
  override def fix(implicit doc: SemanticDocument): Patch = {
    doc.tree
      .collect {
        case Term.Apply(fun, args) =>
          args.zipWithIndex.collect {
            case (t @ Lit.Boolean(_), i) =>
              fun.symbol.info match {
                case Some(info) =>
                  info.signature match {
                    case method: MethodSignature
                        if method.parameterLists.nonEmpty =>
                      val parameter = method.parameterLists.head(i)
                      val parameterName = parameter.displayName
                      Patch.addLeft(t, s"$parameterName = ")
                    case _ =>
                      // Do nothing, the symbol is not a method
                      Patch.empty
                  }
                case None =>
                  // Do nothing, we don't have information about this symbol.
                  Patch.empty
              }
          }
      }
      .flatten
      .asPatch
  }
}
```

Inspecting the above two code snippets shows that ScalaMeta can parse a Scala source into type `Source`. ScalaFix seems to parse the same into an `implicit SemanticDocument`. The `SemanticDocument` has field `tree` which is implemented by ScalaMeta which results into a traversable AST data structure just like the one produced by parsing source file as type `Source`. This shows the relationship between ScalaMeta and ScalaFix. However, my concern is that I need to load a Scala source code and use ScalaFix on it to access `symbol.info` but the `ScalaFix` documentation does not show how to do this.

When I attempt to load source file as a `SemanticDocument` like this in the first code snippet instead of `Source`:

```
 val tree = input.parse[SemanticDocument].get
```

I get an error that `no parameters found for parameter parse in parse[SemanticDocument]`. Also note that trying to use `symbol.info`
in the first code snippet also produces errors about implicit types. This is not the case with the second code snippet as the loaded `doc` parameter is an `implicit parameter of type SemanticDocument`.

**So how does ScalaFix load source files as `SemanticDocument`?**